# Get UITouch from UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, uipangesturerecognizer

Is it possible to get a UITouch object through UIPanGestureRecognizer? How could I do?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

As [Apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer), **you haven't a property to get the touch** in an `UIGestureRecognizer` object. 
But you can subclass the `UIGestureRecognizer` class, in order to override `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and so on, retrieving so the `UITouch` objects.

If can be useful, have also a look to `locationOfTouch:inView:`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue:

**PanGestureRecognizer.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface PanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer {

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end

@protocol PanGestureRecognizer <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

- (void) panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr movedWithTouches:(NSSet*)touches andEvent:(UIEvent *)event;


@end
```

**PanGestureRecognizer.m file**

```
#import "PanGestureRecognizer.h"


@implementation PanGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(panGestureRecognizer:movedWithTouches:andEvent:)]) {
        [(id)self.delegate panGestureRecognizer:self movedWithTouches:touches andEvent:event];
    }

}

@end
```

**GestureView.m file**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
        PanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[PanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panRecognition:)];
        panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        [panRecognizer setDelaysTouchesBegan:NO];
        [panRecognizer setDelaysTouchesEnded:NO];
        [panRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
        panRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.keyboardLayoutView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}

- (void)panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer movedWithTouches:(NSSet*)touches andEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
```